# could not parse version number from mysqldump.exe

Tags: database, mysql, rdbms, mysql-workbench

I get an error "could not parse version number from mysqldump.exe: 'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" whenever I'm trying to export a database in mySQL. I think I got this after changing some of my environment variables in my OS.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I haven't messed with my environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with MySql Workbench 6.3 on Windows 7 x64, the error was due to bad python code.  The following was failing:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\wb_admin_control.py
Line 114:     s = re.match(".*Distrib ([\d.a-z]+).*", output)
```

I fixed it and now it works.  Hooray for python!
Being an incredibly lazy/busy person, I simply hard-coded the return values to be 5.7.8, which is the version I am currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to MysqlWorkbench? This occurs when you upgrade to Workbench 5.2.44, and is due to a bug - they bundled the wrong version of mysqldump.exe. A version 5.2.45 has silently appeared and the bug is fixed in it.

Comment: Johhn, what action would you suggest the OP take? would you suggest he upgrade? Are there any difficulties or challenges involved? BTW, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I had the same problem (with MySQL Workbench). I had 5.2.45 though, and upgraded to 5.2.47 which fixed it.

Comment: I have version 5.2.47 and it is still playing up.